# Two finger left and right swipe on trackpad does not work under Lion

Tags: macos, mac, trackpad

On one user account on one of my family macbook air machines (all with the latest version of Lion) the two finger trackpad swipe left and right to switch back and forth (e.g. between pages in safari) does not work . The three finger swipe and all other gestures work like a charm. Any tips how to make the two finger swipe work again?

Others seem to have this problem, too: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3313418?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Add a similar problem, two-finger swipe stopped working. [Restarting the dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/195665/109005) fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked System Preferences? Go to System Preferences -> Trackpad -> More Gestures and look at the top option (swipe between pages). If it is off, turn it on.

Comment: Of course this is set.

Comment: @vilmoskörte Just putting it out there, you wouldn't believe how bad some people are with computers.