# Can't go fullscreen in any app

Tags: finder, fullscreen

For several weeks, I haven't been able to go full-screen in any app on my laptop.  I thought it was a Chrome problem with YouTube, because when I hit the full-screen button in a movie (bottom-right corner of the movie) it will expand to fill the browser window, but not the whole screen.  Then to restore, hitting Escape or the exit-full-screen button doesn't get the video to reduce down again.  Reloading the browser page works, though.

However, it's not just a browser problem - I recently discovered that no apps (e.g. Finder, Photos, Terminal, Console) can go full-screen by clicking on the circular green button on the left side of their window bars.

On a random cargo-cult recommendation I saw [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4282843), I trashed my `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist` file & restarted the Finder, but no differences are observed.

When I hit the green maximize button in a Finder window, it seems to crash that window - I can no longer drag that window around & it doesn't respond to any clicks.  Other Finder windows stay fine.

To try to debug, I've poked around in various system logs, but I haven't found anything that looks relevant.  Maybe something to do with the WindowServer?

I'm on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014), running Sierra 10.12.5.

Answer (score 3):

Tried a couple more things, and here's what worked: kill the Dock, then get it to restart.  I did this by doing `killall Dock` in the Terminal.  It didn't restart by itself, so e.g. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> didn't work to switch applications, my desktop had no background, and (of course) there was no Dock.

I launched the Dock again by going into System Preferences & clicking on the Dock pane.

Why did I try killing the Dock?  Because I also noticed that Exposé/Mission Control wasn't working either.  Some searching led me to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170488/osx-yosemite-mission-control-stopped-working), which suggested restarting the Dock.

Comment: This is still a thing in OS X 10.15.7; full screen and exposé stopped working for me recently and killing the dock rectified the issue.

Comment: Still happening at Monterey (`12.6.5`) and killing Dock fixed, thanks Ken!